# PHP $_POST[$variable] in an included file, doesn't recognize the $variable and creates an error message

Tags: php, variables, post

I would like to use "dynamic" $_POSTs, I don't know if I am using the right term but in other words I would like to use for example $_POST[$dynamic_variable] in a function that is in an included file. Because the $dynamic_variable isn't recognized or because I can't use $_POST[something] in included files it doesn't work and I get an error message like Undefined variable: lastname in filename.php.

What is the safe to way to use $_POSTs in included files and when the $_POST[name] is variable?

Thank you!

///// updated - piece of code ///////

```
[code.php]

include("functions.php");

$test_arr = array(
"10|field_name1|500",
"20|field_name2|750",
...
);

checkForm($test_arr);

[functions.php]

function checkForm($test_arr) {
  foreach ($test_arr as $test) {
    $test_details = explode("|", $test);
    $field_name = $test_details[1];
    echo $_POST[$field_name];
  }
}
```

Comment: A function is usually better of getting parameters rather then reading the `$_POST` array. And I'm not sure why you say you can't use `$_POST[$dynamic_variable]` at any portion in the code, as long as `$dynamic_variable` is set. I'd say we need more details about your current code.

Comment: Code will help me to answer this.

Comment: I put some code, code will be improved, just wanted to give a quick example.

Comment: I am so bad. Really bad. I put ids, styles, calsses in my form elements but forgot the names. Sorry all, what a mistake... lol :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$_POST` array is available in all included PHP files. Normally, the `$dynamic_variable` is also available, if you do it like so:

```
$dynamic_variable = 'test';
include('include.php');

// in include.php: 
echo $_POST[$dynamic_variable];
```

But when declaring the `$dynamic_variable` inside a function or class, you don't have access to it outside. You could also declare it as [global](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php) or hand it over as a parameter. Please also read the documentation about [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: It doesn't see to work for me. The only difference compared to your example is that $dynamic_variable is an array with pipes (|) separating different values. I call doThisFunction($dynamic_variable);. doThisFunction($dynamic_variable) is in the included file. I do an explode to separate the values so $dynamic_variable is now $dynamic_arr and the $_POST name is $dynamic_arr[2]. So I am trying to use $_POST[$dynamic_arr[2]] in the function. I also tried for e.g. $post_name = $dynamic_arr[2]. and tried to get $_POST[$post_name] but it doesn't work.

Comment: make a `var_dump($_REQUEST);` and a `var_dump($dynamic_arr);` and check if thy fit.

Comment: making a var_dump made me realize I made a big mistake... thanks for the idea

Answer (score 1):

I would not write if it is smart to use globals like that or not.
Your problem is you tried to access a variable which does not exists, as the error message said.

To avoid the error message, you can do:

```
if(isset($_POST[$your_var_name]){
   //do something with $_POST[$your_var_name]
}
```

Comment: I know I can avoid the error message, what I am trying to do is make it work. I can't use $_POST[something] in a function that is in an included file. The 'something' is variable, I don't know the name and if I knew, I would have called it with the function. Using the isset function will make it safe yes, but it does not tell me how to "reach" the $_POST within the function...

Comment: Your problem is not reaching the $_POST, but rather the value in the variable you put in the parenthesis, as, he is not global ($_POST is).

Comment: are you sure? I think the problem is related to the $_POST and not the $variable inside it. Even if I test it manually with $_POST['field_name'] (field name that I know that I used in the form) it doesn't even work. So it doesn't reach the $_POST at all within the function. Is there anything I have to put in the code to access the $_POST "globally"?

Comment: I am 100% sure, Check with fire bug you really sent that variable/value. `echo` the variable one line before you use it inside the POST.

Comment: it does work with the variable, it is displayed when I echo it.